# make Eclipse equals() / hashCode() use getters

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

Is it possible to make the default Eclipse "Generate hashCode() and equals()" use getters instead of field references? - ie. can I get at the template that it uses?

I'm using Hibernate, and Proxied Objects are only LazyLoaded when getters are used and not from field references. It's an annoyance to be constantly changing it.

The obvious workarounds are to create a template myself or write a plugin - which feels like overkill.

EDIT: Looks like these aren't configurable. I'll pose this as a question for the JBoss Tools Group (They make some plugins for Hibernate).

Comment: I don't see that option in my Eclipse (checked Refactor menu)... where is it?

Comment: Eclipse 3.4 it's under the Source menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a solution, rather workaround - but you might try generate `equals()`, then use 'encapsulate field' refactoring to replace all field acceses to use getters/setters (it works inside class also).

Comment: This works! Thanks. It changes all access to the field in the class but does so in a reasonable way. Also you have to do each field individually. Better than any other current solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Ohhhh, be carefull with proxing :  http://blog.xebia.com/2008/03/08/advanced-hibernate-proxy-pitfalls/  ;)

Comment: That's the article that got me started with this in the first place. The recommendation for pitfall #1 is to use getters.

Answer (score 0):

I used a [plugin](http://commonclipse.sourceforge.net/index.html) to generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` with [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

Comment: Linking a google search is not very useful. The results are probably very different now from 5 years ago. Do you have a link to the specific plugin you used?